# Runtime error: R6002 Floating point support not loaded

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I am getting Runtime error:R6002 Floating point support not loaded when I want to start simulator.

I have Eclipse Helios with blackberry plugin, I have tried to run simulator from every rim jde but no success.

I had downloaded free registry repair tools from net and run that but no success.

[image]